# How to create a Qrcode list of names in r

Tags: r, list, qr-code

I have file with 2000 names, here a sample:

```
Name
João
Paulo
Fernando 
Eduardo
Pedro
```

And I would like to generate automatically a list with the names and Qrcodes like this:

[image]

But I would like to control the size of Qrcode images, to be able to insert as many names as possible on a page, as there are 2000 names.

So, to create all Qrcode images I used this code:

```
library(qrcode)

for(i in 1:2000) {
png(paste0(names[[1]][[i]],".png"))
qrcode_gen(names[[1]][[i]])
dev.off() }
```

But I wasn't able to create a list with all qrcodes and control the size of the figures.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this solution, for a qrcode with 240x240 px:

```
library(qrcode)

names <- data.frame(Nomes = c("Juan","Pedro","Pipo","Arsenio"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
for(i in 1:4) {
png(paste0(names[i,],".png"), width = 240, height = 240)
qrcode_gen(names[i,])
dev.off() }
```

Feel free to ask a question.

Regards,

Alexis

Comment: Thanks, but how I do a list. How I join all names in an unique file like a list, can be in PDF or another format.